# How to show the negation of an odd integer is also odd.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to work out a proof that the negation of any odd integer is also odd.  So $-n = -(2k+1)=-2k-1$,  that's where the proof loses me, I'm not sure how to derive the final form, $2(-k-1)+1$ from $-2k-1$.

Comment: What does "a proof that any odd integer is also odd" mean?

Comment: I agree @lulu maybe an analytic continuation of natural number rules ?

Comment: @lulu sorry mistyped the question.  Updated now.

Comment: does my answer help ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee yes, I added a follow up question

Comment: By contradiction:  if $-n=2\times m$ then $n=2\times (-m)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$-2k-1$

$=-2k-1+0$

$=-2k-1+(2-2)$

$=-2k-1+2-2$

$=-2k-2-1+2$

$=2(-k-1)+2-1$

$=2(-k-1)+1$

Answer (score 1):

place the negative sign on k and decrement to change the sign on the 1:$$-2k-1=2(-k)-1=2(-k-1)+1$$

Comment: Why can you decrement to change the sign on the 1?

Comment: $-1=1-2$ it's simply a regrouping.

Answer (score 1):

So... your definition is:  $n$ is odd if there is an integer $k$ so that $n = 2k+1$?

If $n = 2k + 1$ is odd for any $k$ then $n = 2(k+1) - 1$ is odd.  So if we replace $k$ with $k'=k+1$ we have $n=2k' - 1$ for any $k'$.

So we can define $n$ is odd if either $n$ is in the form $2k + 1$ or if $n$ is in the form $2k -1$.

If $n$ is in the form $2k + 1$ then $-n = -2k -1 = 2(-k) -1$ is in the form $2k -1$ if we replace $k$ with $-k$.

If $n$ is in the form $2k-1$ then $-n = -2k +1 = 2(-k) + 1$ is in the form $2k + 1$ if we replace $k$ with $-k$.

And that's it.

If we want to do it mindless way, we can do $n = 2k+1$ so $-n = -2k-1 = -2k-2 + 1 = 2(-k-1) + 1$.

But I call that "mindless" because it is relying on mindlessly memorizing $n = 2k+1$ is a "formula" for being odd without thinking about what odd *means*.  (It's not evenly divisible by two.... so it's either $1$ too big *OR* one too small to be divisible by two.)

And if you want to do it a *thorough* way:

If Let $-n = -2k -1 = 2m + 1$.  Solve for $m$.

$2m = -2k -1 -1 =-2k-2$

$m = -k-1$.

So $n = 2(-k-1) + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof in a different vein than the others. First, the negation of an even integer is clearly even ($-2k = 2(-k))$. So, if $n$ is odd, but $-n$ is even, then $-(-n) = n$ is also even, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$\bmod 2\!:\,\ n\equiv 1\!\!\overset{\rm negate\!\!}\iff\! -n\equiv 1,\, $ by $\,-1\equiv 1$